# Error: FFMPEG not found

Tags: ffmpeg, discord.js

I am making a discord bot with Discord.js and I got this error:

> "Error: FFMPEG not found"

However, I already installed it by doing `npm i ffmpeg-binaries`.

Here is the console: https://hastebin.com/poruqiwewe.coffeescript

How could I fix this?

Comment: Provide the most important part of your code here, not outside of SO.

Comment: Seems like you have a async function inside your code without try catch...

theres any part of your code with I/O or asking for external process (like database, server...) ???

Since you're having problem with FFMPEG, it's probably inside the function you call ffmpeg commands. Post here your code, please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install ffmpeg-binaries globally, so use the follwing command:

```
npm i -g ffmpeg-binaries
```